# Changing span text when a seperate div's class changes - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

Thanks in advance for taking a look at my question.

I have a div with a background image and when it is clicked, I am adding another class which changes this image.

I also want to change some text in a span that I have when this div is clicked.

I've attempted it below, but it has stopped the class from being added:

```
$('.rpLeftArm').click(function () {

            $('.rpLeftArm').addClass("rpLeftArmActive")
            $('#currentStep').html("Pick up the hand furthest away from you and place the back of their hand onto their opposite cheek. <span style="color: Red;">Keep your hand there to guide and support their head as you roll them.</span>");
        });
```

I've tried putting the span text change into another function that is triggered but I'm doing that wrong too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your markup look like? Is the span a child of the div?

Comment: Also you are missing semicolon after first line inside function.

Comment: :::::::::::::::::::::::)))))))))))))))))  Beauty ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put single quotes around your SPAN `<span style='color:red;'>`

```
$('.rpLeftArm').click(function () {    
      $('.rpLeftArm').addClass("rpLeftArmActive");
      $('#currentStep').html("Pick up.... <span style='color: red;'>Keep your...</span>");
});
```

Comment: @lauw0203 oh, no problem :) thank you! Instead of `'` you can also escape your double quotes using `\"`